# How do I start the step counter service in the background?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-service, android-sensors

I have a step counter service. It works fine when the app is open. How do I make the service count the steps when the app is closed? When you close the application, the number of steps does not increase, this makes the application useless...  I found information about "batching", but did not find a normal use case.

```
[Service(Exported = true, Enabled = true,
         Label = "StepCounterService")]
public class StepCounterService : Service, ISensorEventListener
{
    private SensorManager sManager;
    private long currentStepsCount = 0;

    private long overSteppers = 0;

    private DateTime lastUpdateTime;

    public event EventHandler<long> StepUpdated;

    private long _steps = 0;
    public long Steps
    {
        get
        {
            UpdateValue(_steps);
            return _steps;
        }
        private set { _steps = value; }
    }

    public static StepCounterService Current { get; private set; }

    public StepCounterService()
    {

    }

    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        lastUpdateTime = AppPreferences.Get(nameof(lastUpdateTime), nameof(Class), new DateTime());
        overSteppers = AppPreferences.Get(nameof(overSteppers), nameof(Class), 0L);
        InitSensorService();
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        Current = this;
    }

    public void InitSensorService()
    {
        sManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.SensorService) as SensorManager;
        sManager.RegisterListener(this, sManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.StepCounter), SensorDelay.Fastest);
    }

    public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, [GeneratedEnum] SensorStatus accuracy)
    {
    }

    public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Values[0] == 0)
        {
            overSteppers = 0;
            AppPreferences.Save(overSteppers, nameof(overSteppers), nameof(Class));
            currentStepsCount = AppPreferences.Get(nameof(currentStepsCount), nameof(Class), 0L);
        }
        UpdateValue((long)e.Values[0]);
        Steps = (long)e.Values[0] - overSteppers + currentStepsCount;
        StepUpdated?.Invoke(this, Steps);
    }

    private void UpdateValue(long defaultValue)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Date > lastUpdateTime.Date)
        {
            lastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
            overSteppers = defaultValue;
            Steps = 0;
            currentStepsCount = 0;
        }
    }

    private void SaveData()
    {
        AppPreferences.Save(lastUpdateTime, nameof(lastUpdateTime), nameof(Class));
        AppPreferences.Save(overSteppers, nameof(overSteppers), nameof(Class));
        AppPreferences.Save(_steps, nameof(currentStepsCount), nameof(Class));
    }

    public void StopSensorService()
    {
        sManager.UnregisterListener(this);
        sManager.Dispose();
        SaveData();
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        SaveData();
        base.OnDestroy();

    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I start the app, I start the service:

```
MyApp.Context.StartService(new Intent(MyApp.Context, typeof(StepCounterService)));
```

Comment: You could use foreground service.